# How to make this algorithm lazy? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, lazy-evaluation

Let's consider a function `P(n)`, which takes natural numbers as inputs and returns such outputs:

```
P(1) = [[0], [1]]
P(2) = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
P(3) = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
P(4) = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

I don't know how this is called formally (*combinations?*), but I think this example is sufficient to understand what I have in mind.

I've used Java for my implementation:

```
static byte[][] permutate(int n) {
    byte[][] ps = new byte[1 << n][n];
    go(ps, 0, ps.length / 2, ps.length, n - 1);
    return ps;
}

static void go(byte[][] as, int l, int m, int h, int depth) {
    if (depth < 0)
        return;

    for (int i = l, j = m; i < m && j < h; ++i, ++j) {
        as[i][depth] = 0;
        as[j][depth] = 1;
    }

    go(as, l, (l + m) / 2, m, depth - 1);
    go(as, m, (m + h) / 2, h, depth - 1);
}
```

This implementation returns correct results, but its memory usage grows **exponentially**, specifically in `O(2^n)`!

---

Here's what I would like to have: this function, but lazy! Generating these tuples (they're really arrays, but that's beside the point) just when they're needed and discarding the ones already used. So, my question:

Is it possible for this function to return an iterator instead of an array? If so, how?

Comment: It looks like what you're doing is called permutation. You can look at functional interfaces and have your lambda return the next permutation.

Comment: How would **lazy** be any better on memory? Recursions are bad when a compiler is not tail optimised. And your recursion is not even a tail recursion.

Comment: One thing that might be worth considering is the fact that, for any input number _n_, the output is essentially the binary representation of all of the numbers  from 0 through (2^n) - 1

Comment: @Prashant My reasoning was that by generating new tuples on demand and discarding old ones, only one is stored in memory at a time.

Comment: @Jordan That's actually quite brilliant! I have a feeling this one will be the most efficient, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a different approach that works without using recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Iterator<byte[]> iterator = new PermutationIterator(4);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(iterator.next()));
    }
}

private static final class PermutationIterator implements Iterator<byte[]> {
    private final int max;
    private final int n;
    private int current;

    public PermutationIterator(int n) {
        this.n = n;
        this.max = (int) Math.pow(2, n);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current < max;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] next() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            bytes[i] = (byte) ((current >>> i) & 1);
        }
        current++;
        return bytes;
    }
```

However, be aware that this only produces correct results for `n <= 31`. If you want support for bigger `n` you should use `long` or even `BigInteger`.

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: I think I'll stick to reading bits from bare numbers, instead of converting them to `String`s. Thank you!

Comment: @atmostmediocre Yes, I agree, this is indeed better, I've updated my answer.